Error compiling Android library in Plugin Flutter: Direct dependencies on local .aar files are not supported
Context:
1 - I have an application in Flutter to which I am doing a payment integration through a plugin in Flutter connecting it with MethodChannel.
2 - I have a plugin in Flutter from where I am trying to consume an .aar, inside the Android folder that is in the plugin I am making my payment integration, this payment integration is in Native code (Kotlin, Java).
I put the .aar in the libs folder.
enter image description here
from the build.gradle I put implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.aar'])
enter image description here
and when I run the application from my Flutter application, it gives me the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':plugin_flutter:bundleDebugAar'.


Error while evaluating property 'hasLocalAarDeps' of task ':taponphone_mastercard_library:bundleDebugAar'
Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :taponphone_mastercard_library project caused this error: C:\workspace\dev-android\plugin-flutter\android\libs\TTPKernelv22-prod-release.aar


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
I tried creating in the Android folder a new module (File > New > New Module > Android Library)
enter image description here
from settings.gradle include the new module
enter image description here
from the build.gradle I deploy the new module impl-aar as a project and synchronize
enter image description here
and when I run the application from my Flutter application, it gives me the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\workspace\dev-android\plugin-flutter\android\build.gradle' line: 95

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':plugin_flutter'.



Project with path ':impl-aar' could not be found in project ':plugin_flutter'.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
